# General Graphing

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I'd like to create a general graph to illustrate a point (ex. `mx+b` and show `b` is intercept and `m` is slope). I understand that I can create a graph with manual axis naming, but I'd like to also be able to position a label `b` at the intercept, label a couple of points and label `m` as the slope. I understand I may have to input unrelated integer values, but the labeling is what matters.

As an added bonus, I would also want to be able to show how I can adjust certain features and the line would change. (perhaps also a label on the arrow but I forgot to include that in the sketch)

I have attached a couple quick sketchs of the general idea below for clarity. How would I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Your pictures are difficult to understand for myself.

Comment: @TrongVuong1998 - what part is difficult to understand?

Answer (score 3):

For a starting point and only for first image.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\LinearEquation}
{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Slopef}{-1}% slope of the line 1
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Interceptf}{6}% intercept
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Slopes}{-0.9}% slope of the line 2
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Intercepts}{5}% intercept
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[->] (-1,0)--(8.3,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,8.3)node[left]{$y$};
\draw[very thick,red, domain=0:5] plot (\x,\Slopef*\x+\Interceptf);
\node at (0,\Interceptf)(b)[left]{$b$} ;
\def\x1{1.5}
\def\y1{\Slopef*\x1+\Interceptf}
\draw [dashed,blue](\x1,0)node[below]{$x1$}--(\x1,\y1)--(0,\y1)node[left]{$y1$};
\def\x2{3}
\def\y2{\Slopef*\x2+\Interceptf}
\draw [dashed,blue](\x2,0)node[below]{$x2$}--(\x2,\y2)--(0,\y2)node[left]{$y2^\prime$};

\draw[very thick,red, domain=0:5] plot (\x,\Slopes*\x+\Intercepts);
\node at (0,\Intercepts)(b)[left]{$b$} ;
\def\x1{1.5}
\def\y1{\Slopes*\x1+\Intercepts}
\draw [dashed,blue](\x1,0)node[below]{$x1$}--(\x1,\y1)--(0,\y1)node[left]{$y1^\prime$};
\def\x2{3}
\def\y2{\Slopes*\x2+\Intercepts}
\draw [dashed,blue](\x2,0)node[below]{$x2$}--(\x2,\y2)--(0,\y2)node[left]{$y2$};
\draw [<-](2.8,3.5)--(5,3.5)node[right]{Slope $m$};
\draw [<-](2.9,2.5)--(5,2.5)node[right]{Slope $m^\prime$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\LinearEquation
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would one add another line to this? Would there be any way of doing this within the document itself and not setting the specific image as a command?

Comment: @user760900, I have edited my answer. You can insert this file using `standalone` package.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`.  Compile this with `lualatex`.

Follow the link above for tutorials and manuals that explain how MP works.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric u, m, m', b, b';
    u = 1.44cm;
    b = 3.6u;  b' = b + 7/8 u;
    m = -1;  m' = 7/8 m; 

    path xx, yy;
    xx = (left -- 5 right) scaled u;
    yy = xx rotated 90;

    numeric minx, maxx; path ff, gg;
    minx = xpart point 1/16 of xx;
    maxx = xpart point 15/16 of xx;
    ff = (minx, minx * m + b) -- (maxx, maxx * m + b); 
    gg = (minx, minx * m' + b') -- (maxx, maxx * m' + b'); 

    z0 = point 0.4 of ff;
    z1 = point 0.54 of ff;
    z1 0 = whatever [point 0 of gg, point 1 of gg]; x1 0 = x0;
    z1 1 = whatever [point 0 of gg, point 1 of gg]; x1 1 = x1;

    forsuffixes @=0, 1:
        draw (x@, 0) -- z@ -- (0, y@) dashed evenly scaled 3/4;
        draw z@ -- z1 @ -- (0, y1 @) dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
        label.bot("$x_{" & decimal @ & "}$", (x@, 0));
        label.lft("$y_{" & decimal @ & "}$", (0, y@));
        label.lft("$y'_{" & decimal @ & "}$", (0, y1 @));
    endfor

    draw ff withcolor 2/3 red;
    draw gg withcolor 3/4 blue;
    drawarrow xx; drawarrow yy;

    label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
    label.top("$y$", point 1 of yy);

    dotlabel.urt("$b$", (0, b));
    dotlabel.urt("$b'$", (0, b'));

    draw thelabel("slope: $m=" & decimal m & "$", 7 up)
        rotated angle (1, m) shifted point 2/3 of ff;
    draw thelabel("slope: $m'=" & decimal m' & "$", 7 up)
        rotated angle (1, m') shifted point 2/3 of gg;
        
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The syntax to get the `y'` points is a bit tricky; but MP allows spaces between elements of a variable `suffix` so `z0 1` is a valid name for a variable, and the usual `z` macro magic, means that `x0 1` and `y0 1` refer to the x and y parts as usual.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the arrow or does that become extremely difficult? Would you happen to know if it is possible to run this on Overleaf?

Comment: No, an arrow is really easy...

Comment: And yes you can run this on Overleaf -- just be sure to choose `lualatex` as the formatting engine in the options.

Comment: How would I add the arrow and vertical shift the labels? The labels are touching the line they are labeling which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: If you want to make changes, then I suggest that you read the tutorials and manuals that you can find at the link at the top of my answer.